# How to use ts compiler api or ts-morph to get and serialize type information

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I am trying to use the Typescript API to get information from typescript file that imports types from other sources.

I got common type:

```js
// example.types.ts

export interface Example<T> {
  description: string;
  title: string;
  element: T;
}
```

Then some element component or class I want to prepare example for

```js
// Canvas.ts

interface ICanvasConfig {
  name: string;
  size: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}

export const Canvas = (config: ICanvasConfig): void => {
  console.log(config);
};
```

And this is the target file I want to parse

```js
// Canvas.example.ts

import type { Example } from './example.types';

import { Canvas } from './Canvas';

const exampleMeta: Example<typeof Canvas> = {
  title: 'Canvas Element',
  description: 'Element used for..',
  element: Canvas
};

export default exampleMeta;
```

What I'm expecting is to get at the end something like

```json
{
  title: {
     value: 'Canvas Element',
     type: 'string'
  }
  description: {
    value: 'Element used for..',
    type: 'string',
  },
  element: {
    value: Canvas, // real value
    type: {
      name: 'function',
      args: [{
          name: 'string',
          size: {
            width: 'number',
            height: 'number'
          }
      }],
      ret: 'void'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use `ts` compiler and `ts-morph` but all I do is beating around the bush.
I wont publish my solution attempts not to distract you, but it seems I don't understand the inner structure of ts nodes to get what I need. Maximum what I got playing around is detecting title, description as a string but `any` type for element.

**So my question is it actually possible using these tools? If yes then how? Are there any better solutions to achieve what I need?**

Or if you ever faced with similar problems sharing your experience would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to serialize type information including generics. That's a tall order. There may be some limited support in some tools but you're going to run into a plethora of scenarios that aren't supported so you need to study what your tool supports and your restrict yourself to the subset of the language type system that it understands.

Comment: It can be restricted within the example above. My though was, if typescript can understand it, then it is possible to extract that information and parse it to readable structure. Type information could be extracted in recursive manner, kind of simple. Issues start when type is exported/imported and now there are also generic which docs I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using ts-morph with the code below.
This code only works for the example code you provided, but it should be easy to implement a more generic solution using recursion.

I also found a related GitHub issue "Question: Is there a simple way to get a type reduced to only primitives?" and it has a library for expanding types https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/1204#issuecomment-961546054, although it does not extract values such as 'Canvas Element'. To use that add `type exampleMeta = typeof exampleMeta` to `Canvas.example.ts` and run `import { typeFootprint } from "./typeFootprint"; console.log(typeFootprint("src/Canvas.example.ts", "exampleMeta"));` to get the string *1.

```js
import { Project, SyntaxKind } from "ts-morph";
import util from "util"  // for displaying a deep object

const project = new Project({})

// Assuming the files `example.types.ts`, `Canvas.ts`, and `Canvas.example.ts` are in `./src`.
project.addSourceFilesAtPaths("src/**/*.ts")
const exampleMeta = project.getSourceFile("src/Canvas.example.ts")!.getVariableDeclaration("exampleMeta")!

const exampleMetaValue = exampleMeta
    // "go to definition"
    .getFirstChildByKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.Identifier)
    .getDefinitionNodes()[0]!

    // get the initializer `{ title: ..., description: ..., ... }`
    .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.VariableDeclaration)
    .getInitializerOrThrow()

// "go to type definition"
const exampleMetaType = exampleMeta
    .getType()

console.log(util.inspect({
    // You can list properties with `exampleMetaType.getProperties().map((property) => property.getName())`
    title: {
        value: exampleMetaValue
            // .title
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression)  // You can check the kind with `.isKind()` or `.getKindName()`
            .getPropertyOrThrow("title")

            // get the initializer `Create Element`
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.PropertyAssignment)
            .getInitializerOrThrow()
            .getText(),
        type: exampleMetaType
            // .title
            .getPropertyOrThrow("title")
            .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)
            .getText(),
    },
    description: {
        value: exampleMetaValue
            // .description
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression)
            .getPropertyOrThrow("description")

            // get the initializer `Element used for..`
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.PropertyAssignment)
            .getInitializerOrThrow()
            .getText(),
        type: exampleMetaType
            // .description
            .getPropertyOrThrow("description")
            .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)
            .getText(),
    },
    element: {
        value: exampleMetaValue
            // .element
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression)
            .getPropertyOrThrow("element")

            // get the initializer `Canvas`
            .asKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.PropertyAssignment)
            .getInitializerOrThrow()

            .getText(),
        type: {
            name: exampleMetaType
                // .element
                .getPropertyOrThrow("element")
                .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)
                .getCallSignatures().length > 0 ? "function" : "",
            args: exampleMetaType
                // .element
                .getPropertyOrThrow("element")
                .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)
                // Parse '(config: ICanvasConfig) => void'
                .getCallSignatures()[0]!
                .getParameters().map((arg) => {
                    const iCanvasPropertyType: any = {}
                    for (const iCanvasConfigProperty of arg.getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta).getProperties()) {
                        iCanvasPropertyType[iCanvasConfigProperty.getName()] = iCanvasConfigProperty
                            .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)
                            .getText()  // TODO: Parse '{ width: number; height: number; }'
                    }
                    return iCanvasPropertyType
                }),
            ret: exampleMetaType
                // .element
                .getPropertyOrThrow("element")
                .getTypeAtLocation(exampleMeta)

                // Parse '(config: ICanvasConfig) => void'
                .getCallSignatures()[0]!
                .getReturnType()
                .getText(),   // .getFlags() & TypeFlags.Void === true
        },
    },
}, { depth: null }))
```

*1

```js
type exampleMeta = {
  description: string;
  title: string;
  element(config: {
    name: string;
    size: {
      width: number;
      height: number;
    };
  }): void;
}
```